# Can you push synchronization costs onto one thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, overhead

I have two threads: a primary thread that does the main processing of the application, and a secondary thread that receives data batches from the primary thread and processes and outputs them, either to the user, to a file, or over the network. In general, data should be processed at a much faster rate than it is produced. I would like to ensure that the main thread never waits for the secondary thread. The secondary thread can accept any amount of overhead, expanding buffers, redoing work, and so on, with the sole objective of maximizing performance of the main thread. Ideally the main thread will never `synchronize` at all. Is there any way to push synchronization costs onto one thread in Java?

Comment: Have you proven that you have a problem with blocking? Does using a simple `LinkedBlockingQueue` not work?

Comment: There is no reason for the first thread to wait for the secondary thread, except for accessing the shared data structure used to exchange data. This should be blazingly fast, and rare since you put batches of data to this data structure, and since the secondary thread rarely gets items from it (it spends most of its time doing IO). Where is the code? Have you proven there was a synchronization problem?

Comment: Right now the program is under design, and I thought this question might be useful in general for programs where most of the logic is in one thread.

Comment: Martin had given an presentation on lock-free queue for single writer single consumer, https://github.com/mjpt777/examples/tree/master/src/java/uk/co/real_logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an outline of a solution:

1. The main thread works in isolation for some time, piling up data into a collection;
2. when it has generated a nice batch, it:

   i. creates a new collection for itself;

   ii. sets the filled-up collection aside, available to be picked up by the reading thread;

   iii. CASes this collection into an `AtomicReference`.
3. The reading thread polls this `AtomicReference` for updates;
4. when it notices it has been set, it picks up the batch, CASing `null` into the shared reference, so that the main thread knows it can put another collection in.

This has negligible coordination costs for the main thread (just one CAS operation per batch) assuming that the reference is always already `null` when it's time to share a new batch.

The reading thread may run a busy loop polling the shared reference, sleeping a small amount of time each time it reads `null`. The best technique to make the thread sleep for a really short time is

```
LockSupport.parkNanos(1);
```

which will typically sleep for some 30 µs and the whole loop will consume about 2-3% CPU time. You could use a longer pause, of course, if you want to bring down the CPU time even more.

Note that coordination techniques which make the thread wait in a wait set impose a very large latency on both sides, so you should stay away from them if, say, 1 ms latency is a big concern for you.

Comment: How does a CAS affect reorderings in the CPUs Load Ordering Buffer (LOB) and Store Ordering Buffer (SOB)?

Comment: I always recommend not to think at such a low level when reviewing thread safety of a Java program. If you know you have a *happens before* edge where you need it, you have correctness guaranteed. The low-level reasoning only enters when considering latencies at the microsecond level or lower.

Comment: Thanks Marko, that was what I wanted to verify.  That the CAS would place a happens before edge for all reads and writes that happened for the batch that lead up to the publish.

Comment: Yes, unless you use the special-purpose `weakCompareAndSet`, you'll always get *happens-before* for CAS operations in Java. BTW at the low level, I think all CPU's CAS operations guarantee total ordering (x86 certainly does this).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is
a BlockingQueue without size limit (LinkedBlockingQueu) as the was of communication would prevent your main thread from 'synchronization' costs if you meant by them waiting for other thread when sending the data.

Comment: I agree that this is a simple approach, and an excellent place to start.  But how does this avoid 'synchronization' costs?

Comment: from the question 'synchrnozation costs' seems to refer to the thread waiting. The main thread, should never wait when writing to the queue.